# tomkat в контейнере docker не отображает страницы

Tags: java, docker, tomcat

возникла необходимость контейнеризировать мое приложение JavaEE. Создаю контейнер для mysql, работает по логам. Создаю контейнер приложения, по логам все работает, подключается к контейнеру mysql. Но вот проблема, когда я захожу на любой адрес в браузере, скажем, http://localhost:8080/login, то возникает такая проблема, возникает ошибка 404: `The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists. .`

Когда я захожу на http://localhost:8080/, я получаю страницу

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это подтверждает, что приложение работает в контейнере.

Без контейнера, когда запускаю приложение, все работает.

Вот пример страницы входа:

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/login")
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private AuthenticationService authenticationService;

    @Override
    public void init() {
        this.authenticationService = (AuthenticationService) getServletContext().getAttribute("authenticationService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/view/login-page.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        final String email = request.getParameter("email");
        final String password = request.getParameter("password");

        if (authenticationService.isAuthenticated(email, password)){
            final HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            session.setAttribute("email", email);
            response.sendRedirect("/tasks-menu");
        }else {
            response.setContentType("text/HTML; charset=UTF-8");
            response.getWriter().write("Неверный логин или пароль");
        }

    }
}
```

Мой Dockerfile

```
FROM tomcat:9

COPY target/javaee_rest_jdbc_todo_list.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/

CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

Команды для запуска проекта

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 --name app --net javaee-net task_api
docker exec -it app /bin/bash  
mv webapps webapps2
mv webapps.dist/ webapps
exit
```

Структура проекта

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А так же проект на  гитхабе: https://github.com/MatveyAndrosyukk/javaee_rest_jdbc_todo_list.

Comment: Приложение должно быть доступно по ссылке http://localhost:8080/javaee_rest_jdbc_todo_list/login

Comment: Не доступно, тот же самый 404

Comment: Попробуйте зайти на главной странице в Manager App. Логин и пароль можно подсмотреть в `/usr/local/tomcat/conf/tomcat-users.xml` внизу файла, там должна быть раскомментирована строка вида `<user username="admin" password="admin12345" roles="admin-gui,admin-script,manager-gui,manager-script,manager-jmx,manager-status"/>`.  После логина можно увидеть ваше запущенное приложение и его статус

Comment: Везде пишут, что нужно закомментировать строчк в config.xml, но как это сделать, я не могу запустить ни 1 команду для редактирования файлов

Comment: У меня получилось зайти в tomcat manager, но что делать дальше? Все равно никак не могу достучаться до приложения

Comment: В админке томката должны быть ссылки на приложения томката `/` , '/docs', `/manager` и ссылка на Ваше приложение, что-то типа `/javaee_rest_jdbc_todo_list`  вести должна сюда http://localhost:8080/javaee_rest_jdbc_todo_list , есть такая? При переходе на нее должна открыться стартовая страница приложения. И какой у нее статус?